# Using Linq to Entity Framework to run query to return big hierarchy

Tags: linq-to-entities

Second question I have had to ask about Linq! So I will admit I have just started using it, and I am a bit of a learner at it. But I got a great answer for my last query, so thought I would chance my luck again! I have been fighting with this for basically a day now!

I have a long hierarchy that I wish to return all of it, but at the end of the hierarchy I need it to be conditional.

I have this hierarchy:

```
Person (object) -> Party (object) -> Workers (collection) 
-> WorkerOperatorAssignment (collection) -> Operator (object)
-> OperatorBusinessAssignment (collection) -> BusinessUnit (object)
```

This is from Person to BusinessUnit through the Operator table as I need to be sure that the Operator rows are for that Person, and straight to the BusinessUnit as I need to ensure the Operator is also assigned to a BusinessUnit, but there is also a shorter route from Person to BusinessUnit direct (fyi)

```
Person (object) -> BusinessUnits (collection)
```

I have PersonID for the first table, and also BusinessUnitID for the last table. I basically need to return a Person object that contains each part of the hierarchy, and all Operator records that are in a certain BusinessUnit.

I have this piece of Linq so far and it returns all the way to Operator, but returns ALL Operators in the query, not just the ones that have a certain association with a BusinessUnit. This is due to not being able to put a where clause in an Include statement.

```
var PersonQuery = 
    DbContext.People.Where(p => p.PersonPartyID == personPartyID)
    .Include(p => p.Party.Workers.Select(w => w.WorkerOperatorAssignments.Select(a => a.Operator)));
```

I have lazy loading turned off, and I need this to be done in one query if possible.

How would I limit the Operators returned so that the only ones returned are those which are in a BusinessUnit?

UPDATE:

I have went back to my original query and completed it, as per Nathan's answer. It has become a complex query.

```
(from P in DbContext.People
 where P.PersonPartyID == personPartyID
 select new
 {
   PersonObject = P,
   PartyObject = P.Party,
   WorkerObject = P.Party.Workers.FirstOrDefault(),
   BusinessUnit = P.BusinessUnits.Where(bu => bu.BusinessUnitID == businessUnitID).FirstOrDefault(),
   WorkerOperatorAssignments = P.Party.Workers.SelectMany(w => w.WorkerOperatorAssignments)
                                             .Where(a => a.Operator.OperatorBusinessUnitAssignments.Any(oa => oa.BusinessUnit.BusinessUnitID == businessUnitID)),
   Operator = P.BusinessUnits.Where(bu => bu.BusinessUnitID == businessUnitID)
                             .SelectMany(bu => bu.OperatorBusinessUnitAssignments)
                             .Select(a => a.Operator)
 }).SingleOrDefault();
```

The problem now, is that behind the scenes Entity Framework seems to auto attach every object to the Person object EXCEPT the BusinessUnit.

So after this query, I need to do this:

```
// get the person object
if (PersonQuery != null)
{
    // get the person object
    Person ReturnObject = PersonQuery.PersonObject;

    // now attach the business unit
    ReturnObject.BusinessUnits.Add(PersonQuery.BusinessUnit);
 }
 else
 {
    return null;
 }
```

What is wrong with my query, that I need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/0877f2f3-32d4-43cd-bd13-90e6c2840e34
You could also look at CreateSourceQuery if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: I looked into this at first, but the query got complex so I was hoping there was an easier way, I am in the middle of updating my question with the new Query